# Android 1.6 emulator crash

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, emulation

I have 3 1.6 emulators that continue to crash a few minutes after I start them (Note my 2.1 and 2.2 emulators work fine).  I made a brand new one today (without the market enabled or SD card support) and it still had the same problem.  The strange thing is they crash without using them.  I just start them up, walk away for 5 minutes and boom, the emulator is gone from the DDMS devices view in Eclipse.  It is still visible on screen, and I can run the standard apps it comes with, but Eclipse no longer recognizes it to run/debug any apps on it.

The log is enormous from start up to crash and it has what looks to be a ton of faults, so I'm going to try to post some individual logs rather than the whole darn thing.

Any thoughts what I could do?  Thanks all

Error list:

```
    12-31 14:32:26.592: ERROR/MemoryHeapBase(67): error opening /dev/pmem: No such file or directory
    12-31 14:32:26.592: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(67): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
    12-31 14:32:26.692: ERROR/libEGL(67): couldn't load <libhgl.so> library (Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library 'libhgl.so' not found)
    12-31 14:32:27.222: ERROR/libEGL(78): couldn't load <libhgl.so> library (Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library 'libhgl.so' not found)
    12-31 14:32:49.081: ERROR/BatteryService(67): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/usb/online'
    12-31 14:32:49.081: ERROR/BatteryService(67): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_vol'
    12-31 14:32:49.081: ERROR/BatteryService(67): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_temp'
    12-31 14:32:49.851: ERROR/EventHub(67): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
    12-31 14:32:49.851: ERROR/EventHub(67): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
    12-31 14:32:50.122: ERROR/System(67): Failure starting core service
    12-31 14:32:50.122: ERROR/System(67): java.lang.SecurityException
    12-31 14:32:50.122: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
    12-31 14:32:50.122: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
    12-31 14:32:50.122: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
    12-31 14:32:50.122: ERROR/System(67):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:162)
    12-31 14:32:50.122: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(67): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
    12-31 14:33:02.751: ERROR/ActivityThread(141): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
    12-31 14:33:06.832: ERROR/ActivityThread(141): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
    12-31 14:33:02.868: ERROR/ActivityThread(119): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
    12-31 14:33:05.538: ERROR/ActivityThread(119): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
    12-31 14:33:06.150: ERROR/ActivityThread(119): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
    12-31 14:33:06.740: ERROR/ActivityThread(119): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
    12-31 14:33:06.890: ERROR/ActivityThread(119): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
    12-31 14:33:07.859: ERROR/ApplicationContext(67): Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/wallpaper-hints.xml
    12-31 14:33:12.489: ERROR/vold(26): Cannot start volume '/sdcard' (volume is not bound)
```

Warn list:

```
12-31 14:32:26.711: WARN/HAL(67): load: module=/system/lib/hw/copybit.goldfish.so error=Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library '/system/lib/hw/copybit.goldfish.so' not found
12-31 14:32:26.711: WARN/HAL(67): load: module=/system/lib/hw/copybit.default.so error=Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library '/system/lib/hw/copybit.default.so' not found
12-31 14:32:26.721: WARN/HAL(67): load: module=/system/lib/hw/copybit.goldfish.so error=Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library '/system/lib/hw/copybit.goldfish.so' not found
12-31 14:32:26.721: WARN/HAL(67): load: module=/system/lib/hw/copybit.default.so error=Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library '/system/lib/hw/copybit.default.so' not found
12-31 14:32:26.721: WARN/HAL(67): load: module=/system/lib/hw/overlay.goldfish.so error=Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library '/system/lib/hw/overlay.goldfish.so' not found
12-31 14:32:26.721: WARN/HAL(67): load: module=/system/lib/hw/overlay.default.so error=Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library '/system/lib/hw/overlay.default.so' not found
12-31 14:32:26.832: WARN/EntropyService(67): unable to load initial entropy (first boot?)
12-31 14:32:26.832: WARN/EntropyService(67): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/entropy.dat
12-31 14:32:26.832: WARN/EntropyService(67):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:231)
12-31 14:32:26.832: WARN/EntropyService(67):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80)
12-31 14:32:26.832: WARN/EntropyService(67):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:135)
12-31 14:32:26.832: WARN/EntropyService(67):     at com.android.server.RandomBlock.fromFile(RandomBlock.java:44)
12-31 14:32:26.832: WARN/EntropyService(67):     at com.android.server.EntropyService.loadInitialEntropy(EntropyService.java:88)
12-31 14:32:26.832: WARN/EntropyService(67):     at com.android.server.EntropyService.<init>(EntropyService.java:75)
12-31 14:32:26.832: WARN/EntropyService(67):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:97)
12-31 14:32:27.422: WARN/PackageManager(67): Running ENG build: no pre-dexopt!
12-31 14:32:29.541: WARN/dalvikvm(91): DexOpt: resolve class illegal access: Landroid/text/PackedIntVectorTest; -> Landroid/text/PackedIntVector;
12-31 14:32:29.582: WARN/dalvikvm(91): DexOpt: resolve class illegal access: Lcom/android/internal/os/LoggingPrintStreamTest$TestPrintStream; -> Lcom/android/internal/os/LoggingPrintStream;
12-31 14:32:43.822: WARN/PackageParser(67): Intent filter for activity ActivityIntentInfo{438019c8 com.android.camera.ReviewImage} defines no actions
12-31 14:32:44.802: WARN/PackageParser(67): Intent filter for activity ActivityIntentInfo{438ba948 com.example.android.apis.media.MediaPlayerDemo_Audio} defines no actions
12-31 14:32:44.802: WARN/PackageParser(67): Intent filter for activity ActivityIntentInfo{438c4680 com.example.android.apis.media.MediaPlayerDemo_Video} defines no actions
12-31 14:32:48.231: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
12-31 14:32:48.241: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.providers.contacts
12-31 14:32:48.241: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cp in package com.android.providers.contacts
12-31 14:32:48.241: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.WRITE_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
12-31 14:32:48.241: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.READ_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
12-31 14:32:48.241: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.settings
12-31 14:32:48.251: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.development
12-31 14:32:48.251: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES in package com.android.development
12-31 14:32:48.251: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.YouTubeUser in package com.android.development
12-31 14:32:48.251: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.ACCESS_GOOGLE_PASSWORD in package com.android.development
12-31 14:32:48.251: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.google.android.providers.enhancedgooglesearch
12-31 14:32:48.251: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.OTHER_SERVICES in package com.google.android.providers.enhancedgooglesearch
12-31 14:32:48.251: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.browser
12-31 14:32:48.262: WARN/PackageManager(67): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.contacts
12-31 14:32:48.632: WARN/ActivityManager(67): Unable to start service Intent { act=android.accounts.IAccountsService cmp=com.google.android.googleapps/.GoogleLoginService }: not found
12-31 14:32:48.632: WARN/AccountMonitor(67): Couldn't connect to Intent { act=android.accounts.IAccountsService cmp=com.google.android.googleapps/.GoogleLoginService } (Missing service?)
12-31 14:32:49.174: WARN/HAL(67): load: module=/system/lib/hw/lights.goldfish.so error=Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library '/system/lib/hw/lights.goldfish.so' not found
12-31 14:32:49.181: WARN/HAL(67): load: module=/system/lib/hw/lights.default.so error=Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library '/system/lib/hw/lights.default.so' not found
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67): Unable to add bookmark: com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivityGmail
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivityGmail}
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationContext.java:1670)
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.loadBookmarks(DatabaseHelper.java:498)
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.loadBookmarks(DatabaseHelper.java:526)
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:124)
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.query(SettingsProvider.java:197)
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:129)
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:152)
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.server.PowerManagerService.initInThread(PowerManagerService.java:408)
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.server.PowerManagerService$1.onLooperPrepared(PowerManagerService.java:374)
12-31 14:32:49.431: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:59)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67): Unable to add bookmark: com.android.providers.im/com.android.providers.im.LandingPage
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.android.providers.im/com.android.providers.im.LandingPage}
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationContext.java:1670)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.loadBookmarks(DatabaseHelper.java:498)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.loadBookmarks(DatabaseHelper.java:526)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:124)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.query(SettingsProvider.java:197)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:129)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:152)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.server.PowerManagerService.initInThread(PowerManagerService.java:408)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.server.PowerManagerService$1.onLooperPrepared(PowerManagerService.java:374)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:59)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67): Unable to add bookmark: com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity}
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationContext.java:1670)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.loadBookmarks(DatabaseHelper.java:498)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.loadBookmarks(DatabaseHelper.java:526)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:124)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.query(SettingsProvider.java:197)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:129)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:152)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.server.PowerManagerService.initInThread(PowerManagerService.java:408)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.server.PowerManagerService$1.onLooperPrepared(PowerManagerService.java:374)
12-31 14:32:49.441: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:59)
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67): Unable to add bookmark: com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity}
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationContext.java:1670)
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.loadBookmarks(DatabaseHelper.java:498)
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.loadBookmarks(DatabaseHelper.java:526)
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:124)
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.query(SettingsProvider.java:197)
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:129)
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:152)
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.server.PowerManagerService.initInThread(PowerManagerService.java:408)
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.server.PowerManagerService$1.onLooperPrepared(PowerManagerService.java:374)
12-31 14:32:49.451: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:59)
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67): Unable to add bookmark: com.google.android.youtube/com.google.android.youtube.HomeActivity
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.youtube/com.google.android.youtube.HomeActivity}
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationContext.java:1670)
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.loadBookmarks(DatabaseHelper.java:498)
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.loadBookmarks(DatabaseHelper.java:526)
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:124)
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.query(SettingsProvider.java:197)
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:129)
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:152)
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.server.PowerManagerService.initInThread(PowerManagerService.java:408)
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at com.android.server.PowerManagerService$1.onLooperPrepared(PowerManagerService.java:374)
12-31 14:32:49.482: WARN/SettingsProvider(67):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:59)
12-31 14:32:50.372: WARN/ResourceType(67): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x7f060000
12-31 14:32:50.372: WARN/ResourceType(67): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x7f060001
12-31 14:32:50.421: WARN/ResourceType(67): Failure getting entry for 0x7f060000 (t=5 e=0) in package 0: 0xffffffb5
12-31 14:32:50.891: WARN/ActivityManager(67): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.google.android.server.checkin/.CheckinService }: not found
12-31 14:32:50.891: WARN/SystemServer(67): Using fallback Checkin Service.
12-31 14:32:51.031: WARN/GpsLocationProvider(67): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
12-31 14:32:51.181: WARN/AudioService(67): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-31 14:32:51.181: WARN/AudioService(67): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-31 14:32:51.191: WARN/AudioService(67): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-31 14:32:51.191: WARN/AudioService(67): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-31 14:32:51.191: WARN/AudioService(67): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-31 14:32:51.191: WARN/HeadsetObserver(67): This kernel does not have wired headset support
12-31 14:32:51.421: WARN/ResourceType(67): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x7f03002f
12-31 14:32:51.472: WARN/ResourceType(67): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x7f030000
12-31 14:32:51.491: WARN/ResourceType(67): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x7f030003
12-31 14:32:51.501: WARN/ResourceType(67): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x7f03000e
12-31 14:32:51.511: WARN/ResourceType(67): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x7f030009
12-31 14:32:51.682: WARN/ResourceType(67): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
12-31 14:32:51.682: WARN/StatusBar(67): Icon not found in <system>: 0
12-31 14:32:57.011: WARN/ResourceType(67): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x7f060000
12-31 14:32:57.032: WARN/ResourceType(67): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x7f060001
12-31 14:33:01.292: WARN/UsageStats(67): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.android.sdksetup
12-31 14:33:01.631: WARN/ActivityManager(67): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.ussd.IExtendedNetworkService }: not found
12-31 14:33:02.270: WARN/SystemClock(119): Unable to set rtc to 1293823982: Invalid argument
12-31 14:33:02.868: WARN/Checkin(119): Can't update stat PHONE_GSM_REGISTERED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats
12-31 14:33:05.538: WARN/Checkin(119): Can't update stat PHONE_GPRS_ATTEMPTED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats
12-31 14:33:06.150: ERROR/ActivityThread(119): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
12-31 14:33:06.150: WARN/Checkin(119): Can't update stat PHONE_GPRS_CONNECTED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats
12-31 14:33:06.740: WARN/Checkin(119): Can't update stat PHONE_GPRS_ATTEMPTED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats
12-31 14:33:06.890: WARN/Checkin(119): Can't update stat PHONE_GPRS_CONNECTED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats
12-31 14:33:07.449: WARN/ActivityManager(67): Unable to start service Intent { act=android.accounts.IAccountsService cmp=com.google.android.googleapps/.GoogleLoginService }: not found
12-31 14:33:07.470: WARN/AccountMonitor(141): Couldn't connect to Intent { act=android.accounts.IAccountsService cmp=com.google.android.googleapps/.GoogleLoginService } (Missing service?)
12-31 14:33:08.688: WARN/SurfaceFlinger(67): timeout expired mFreezeDisplay=1, mFreezeCount=0
12-31 14:33:08.799: WARN/WindowManager(67): App freeze timeout expired.
12-31 14:33:08.799: WARN/WindowManager(67): Force clearing freeze: AppWindowToken{43908b48 token=HistoryRecord{4388a4d0 com.android.launcher/.Launcher}}
12-31 14:33:11.049: WARN/SQLiteDirectCursorDriver(67): Found SQL string that ends in ; -- PRAGMA table_info(favorites);
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141): Unable to add favorite: com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity}
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationContext.java:1670)
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherProvider$DatabaseHelper.addShortcut(LauncherProvider.java:562)
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherProvider$DatabaseHelper.loadFavorites(LauncherProvider.java:534)
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherProvider$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(LauncherProvider.java:243)
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherProvider.query(LauncherProvider.java:103)
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:129)
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:152)
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherModel.updateShortcutLabels(LauncherModel.java:652)
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherModel.access$900(LauncherModel.java:50)
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherModel$DesktopItemsLoader.run(LauncherModel.java:759)
12-31 14:33:11.380: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141): Unable to add favorite: com.android.vending/com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity}
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationContext.java:1670)
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherProvider$DatabaseHelper.addShortcut(LauncherProvider.java:562)
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherProvider$DatabaseHelper.loadFavorites(LauncherProvider.java:534)
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherProvider$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(LauncherProvider.java:243)
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherProvider.query(LauncherProvider.java:103)
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:129)
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:152)
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherModel.updateShortcutLabels(LauncherModel.java:652)
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherModel.access$900(LauncherModel.java:50)
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at com.android.launcher.LauncherModel$DesktopItemsLoader.run(LauncherModel.java:759)
12-31 14:33:11.472: WARN/LauncherProvider(141):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is reinstall your 1.6 sdk from default install. After that I would recreate your emulators that you have already created and delete the original emulators that you made.

Comment: I guess that's worth a shot for a fix, but I'd really like to figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: It looks like your SD card is corrupted or when it initialized / saved to the SD card it got corrupted somehow. All of the errors seem to point that it can't access anything.

Comment: Well, I stated in my original post that I made a brand new emulator without an SD card support, so the SD card shouldn't have affected the new emulator.

Comment: I'm thinking that the SDK has a corrupted starting off point and thats why it was creating bad roms.